# Is there a way to install cython-bbox for Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, installation, anaconda

I have Visual Studio installed and am trying to run a Python 3 program which depends on the `cython_bbox` package. I tried to install it with `pip install cython-bbox` on a Windows [Anaconda 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) environment, but I got the following error:

```
  Building wheel for cython-bbox (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\CCL\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CCL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du8dua7h\\cython-bbox\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CCL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du8dua7h\\cython-bbox\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\CCL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-0bojfxq5'
       cwd: C:\Users\CCL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-du8dua7h\cython-bbox\
  Complete output (11 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'cython_bbox' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\CCL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\CCL\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\CCL\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/cython_bbox.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/cython_bbox.obj -Wno-cpp
  cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-cpp'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython-bbox
```

Can this error be solved? What is `/Wno-cpp`? Do I need to edit some source file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just solved this problem. I downloaded the tar.gz file from PyPI, extracted it and edited the source files. To facilitate Windows support, cd into the package directory and then change line 31 in the setup.py file from `extra_compile_args=['-Wno-cpp'],` to `extra_compile_args = {'gcc': ['/Qstd=c99']}`.

Then you can install this package from the local source using `pip install -e /path/cython_bbox-0.1.3.tar/dist/cython_bbox-0.1.3/cython_bbox-0.1.3`. If successful, you should see the following:

```
Installing collected packages: cython-bbox
  Running setup.py develop for cython-bbox
Successfully installed cython-bbox
```

Here's a relevant thread for more info: https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/51

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks, you missed two steps though so for completion I am adding them here in case someone follows this to fix the same error
After the above step:
`python setup.py bdist_wheel`
`pip install dist/cython_bbox-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 18):

The author has since updated the setup to support Windows, but the author has not published to [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index) as of yet. So you can pip install directly from the GitHub repository:

`pip install -e git+https://github.com/samson-wang/cython_bbox.git#egg=cython-bbox`

Comment: Excelent answer !  Thank you